# Problem involving the index of an ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I am making a mock directory. This method is called when a button is clicked, and should display a new student file on the screen. It works perfectly unless I go out of bounds for the arraylist. I know that is an out of bounds exception, but I thought I handled it with the if() statement. For clarification, studentRecord is an arraylist that contains String arrays. These String arrays hold the name, divison, ID, etc of a student.
Here is my code:

```
public void previousStudent(View view){
    counter--;
    if(counter < 0){counter = studentRecords.size();}

    tvID.setText("Student ID: " + studentRecords.get(counter)[0]);
    tvName.setText("Student Name: "+ studentRecords.get(counter)[1] + " " + studentRecords.get(counter)[2]);
    tvDivision.setText("Division: " + studentRecords.get(counter)[3]);
    tvGender.setText("Student Gender: " + studentRecords.get(counter)[4]);
}
```

https://pastebin.com/K0sUr71R

Comment: `studentRecords.size()` is still out of bounds. You're probably looking for `studentRecords.size() - 1`.

Comment: ArrayList are 0 based like arrays.  Hence, from 0 to ArrayList.Size() - 1.

Answer (score 0):

The size of the `List` is not a usable index as the indexes start to 0 for `List`s like for `Array`s.
So only `studentRecords.size()-1` is usable as last index such as.

```
counter = studentRecords.size() - 1;
```

To wrap loop that is before first -> last : use this way.
Or as alternative just disable the "previous" button as you reach the first element that is the `0`th index.

Comment: OP probably wants to start from beginning (or end depending how you see it) of list when code reaches `0`th item therefore just changing `counter = studentRecords.size();` to  `counter = studentRecords.size() - 1;` should be enough.